# how to use ~なあ with 〜な adjective

Tags: words

My course book states that plain form + なあ can be used to express feelings, eg. うらやましいなあ　I envy you. My question is how to use a ~な　adjective with -なあ. eg. would it be 上手なあ or 上手だなあ?

Comment: i believe that both 上手なあ and 上手だなあ are both ok. the difference being the first one is used by women and the second by men.

Comment: ^ 「[上手]{じょうず}なあ」とは言いません・・(「上手ねえ」とは言いますけど)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese,* ～なあis constructed one of three ways

- Sentence with informal ending ～なあ (includes questions ～かなあ)
- Sentence that ends with an informal negative verb ending ～かなあ
- Sentence that ends with informal past verb ～なあ

Examples:

> 高いなあ。
>
> 高いかなあ。
>
> 山田さんは来ないかなあ。
>
> あのけちの吉田がよく金を出したなあ。
>
> 車があったらいいなあ。

Informal ending for ～な adjectives is　だ、so to answer your question, we use the informal sentence ending for the sentence and attach ～なあ

> 彼は日本語上手だなあ。

Hope it helps.